# MATLAB quantiz - mean square distortion

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

have a question regarding mean square distortion returned by MATLAB's quantiz function.

Here is my code:

```
dataset = rand(1,1000)*2-1; 
M1 = 128; 
qlevels1=-1+(2/M1):2/M1:1-(2/M1); 
codebook1 =-1+(1/M1/2):2/M1:1-(1/M1/2); 
[index1, quants1, dist1] = quantiz(dataset, qlevels1, codebook1); 
Qnoise1 = sum((dataset-quants1).^2);
```

My after running my program my $Qnoise1$ and $dist1$ differ by magnitude of `1000`

> $Qnoise1 = 0.0374$
>   $dist1 =   3.7417e-05$

Am I missing something here? Should I multiply qlevels1 by length(dataset) to get correct answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because you use 1000 points and sum them up. You can use `mean` instead of `sum`.

```
Qnoise1 = mean((dataset-quants1).^2);
```